# Reading from channels

Tags: go, concurrency

When reading from channels in Go, I observed that it does not follow perfect synchronization between the publishing function and the consuming function. Strangely enough, if it was a quirk with the CPU scheduling, I would have got different results some of the time. The consumer in `main` seems to consume in multiples two at a time and print them.

Consider the following example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func squares(ch chan int) {
    for i:=0; i<9; i++ {
        val:= i*i;
        fmt.Printf("created val %v \n", val);
        ch <- i*i;
        fmt.Printf("After posting val %v \n", val);
    }
    
    close(ch)
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    go squares(c)
    
    for val := range c{
        fmt.Println(val);
    }
}
```

No matter how many times I run it on Go Playground, I see the following output.

```
created val 0 
After posting val 0 
created val 1 
0
1
After posting val 1 
created val 4 
After posting val 4 
created val 9 
4
9
After posting val 9 
created val 16 
After posting val 16 
created val 25 
16
25
After posting val 25 
created val 36 
After posting val 36 
created val 49 
36
49
After posting val 49 
created val 64 
After posting val 64 
64
```

Shouldn't I be expecting because go would block the `squares` method until `main` has printed it?

```
created val 0 
0
After posting val 0 
...
```

If not then why? If I want perfect synchronization like the above, what should be my way?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: This output is perfectly fine.

Comment: The synchronization happens on the actual channel operations.  The print statements are not synchronized, they are only ordered within the sequence of operations in their respective go routine.

Comment: What to do in case I want perfect synchronization?

Answer (score 0):

You are using an unbuffered channel, so this is what happens.

NOTE: This is not meant as a technically 100% accurate description.

1. main routine starts. It runs until `for val := range c {`. Then it is put to "sleep" as there is no value to be read from c.
2. goroutine for `squares` which was just created is being "awoken". It creates a value and can post it as the other goroutine is already "waiting" for a value on the channel. Then it creates another value and can't post it as the channel now blocks.
3. main routine is "awoken", reads the value, prints it, reads the next value which the other goroutine is already waiting to push. prints it and then is stuck again as there is no new value available.
4. goroutine for `sqares` is "awoken" as it was able to push its value. It prints "After posting", creates a new value, posts it as the other routine is already waiting for one, and creates another one. Then it gets stuck as the other routine is not ready to receive the next value.
5. back to 3)

If you want a "smoother" workflow where the routines don't synchronize on every single value that is being passed through the channel, make a buffered channel:

```golang
c := make(chan int, 3)
```